# can't output the he adjusted value

Tags: c

I have been trying hard but im getting error. 
I want to display the following :
Enter a value:
2.5 
The adjusted value is: 14.000000
but I don't know why i keep getting :
Untitled 11.c:6:9: warning: incomplete format specifier [-Wformat]
        scanf("%l", q);
               ^~
1 warning generated.
Enter a value:The adjusted value is: 0.000000

```
#include <stdio.h>
double SPECIAL_CONST = 5.6;
int main(void)
{
printf("Enter a value:\n");
double q;
scanf("%l", q);
printf("The adjusted value is: %f\n", q*SPECIAL_CONST);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong format specifier (`%l`) for `double`. Use `%lf` to read `double` type value. And `scanf` aspects `double *` type argument but you are passing `double` type argument. Append `q` with `&`.
Change

```
scanf("%l", q);   
//     ^wrong format specifier
```

to

```
scanf("%lf", &q);
```